# sql clarification

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please clarify what this query will return ?

```
SELECT TestCase FROM MyTable  WHERE Verdict = 'PASS' AND 
StartTime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DATE_SUB subtracts a time value from a date, in this case it will subtract 2 months from today's date.

This query will therefore return the field TestCase where Verdict = 'PASS' and the StartTime is within the last 2 months ( StartTime > two months ago).

Answer (score 2):

`DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)` will return the date that was `2` `months` before from present date.

So your query will return all the test cases that have `Verdict` as `'PASS'` and whose `startTime` was within the last 2 months.

Answer (score 0):

All passing test cases that were run (started, to be precise) in the last two months.

Answer (score 0):

This Query will return all the "TestCase" which has the Verdict value is equal to 'PASS' for the past 2 months...that is (current month-2)